# Permutations of the natural numbers that leave a finite set fixed

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, logic

I´m going through the forcing proof of the relative consistency of `every set can be linearly ordered' to ZF. I'm stuck on some technical details regarding permutations of the natural numbers that leave a finite set fixed.

Let $G$ be the permutation group of $\mathbb{N}$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we denote
$$
G_n := \{g \in G \mid gn = n\}
$$
and for finite $J \subset \mathbb{N}$
$$
G_J := \bigcap_{n \in J} G_n.
$$
In other words, by $G_n$ we denote the set of all permutations that leave $n$ fixed, and by $G_J$ those that leave all elements of $J$ fixed.

Now suppose that we have finite $J_1, J_2 \subset \mathbb{N}$ and let $J = J_1 \cap J_2$. I want to show that each permutation $g \in G_J$ can be written as composition of permutations in $G_{J_1} \cup G_{J_2}$. In other words, that $G_J$ is the group generated by $G_{J_1} \cup G_{J_2}$.

Does anyone know how one would go about doing this?

Comment: As a first example, do you see how to do this for $J_1=\{0\}$, $J_2=\{1\}$ and $\pi: x\mapsto x+1$? (Replacing $\mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ so $\pi$ is easier to describe.) The general case is basically just an elaboration of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of our permutations will fix every element of $J$, so we can just remove those elements from $\mathbb{N}$ and suppose that $J=\emptyset$.  Write $J_1=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, and choose distinct elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus (J_1\cup J_2\cup g(J_1))$.  Let $s$ be the permutation that swaps $x_i$ with $a_i$ for each $i$, let $t_1$ be the permutation that swaps $a_i$ with $g(x_i)$ for all $i$ such that $g(x_i)\in J_1$, and let $t_2$ be the permutation that swaps $a_i$ with $g(x_i)$ for all $i$ such that $g(x_i)\not\in J_1$.  Note that $t_2\in G_{J_1}$ and $s,t_1\in G_{J_2}$.  Furthermore, note that $h=g^{-1}t_2t_1s$ fixes every element of $J_1$.  Thus we can write $g=t_2t_1sh^{-1}$, where every term on the right-hand side is in $G_{J_1}$ or $G_{J_2}$.